# Combining arrays on common elements

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've got two identical multi dimension arrays which contain elements `Date` `Hour` `Value` for a range of dates.  There may be missing values in each series.

I'd like to combine into a single array using `Date` and `Hour` as keys:
`Date` `Hour` `Value from array1` `Value from array2`

At the moment my approach is to create a new array based on the earliest/latest date and then populate with the values from each array but wondering if there's a better/easier way.

Comment: This con be done in a fairly straightforward manner using nested scripting.dictionaries

Comment: Can you show us an example of the existing arrays and what you want obtaining after processing? Do you need summarizing the values of both initial arrays for specific date/hour combination?

Comment: @freeflow Thanks, I hadn't come across scripting.dictionaries before but it did the job

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next approach. The following code loads the arrays containing Time, Hour and values from an Excel sheet, involved ranges looking like:

[image: The sheet involved range]

The two ranges "A2:C6", respectively, "F2:F6" will be loaded in two 2D arrays (`arr1` and `arr2`). They will be processed and the processing result will be placed in `arrFin`. The range "J2:K8" represents the processing result:

```
Sub testMatchDayHourValue()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr1, arr2, arrFin, i As Long
 Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet      'use here your necessary sheet
 arr1 = sh.Range("A2:C6").Value 'put the range value in an array
 arr2 = sh.Range("F2:H6").Value 'put the range value in an array
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr1) 'iterate through the first array elements and create uniques keys
    If Not dict.Exists(arr1(i, 1) & " " & Format(arr1(i, 2), "hh:mm")) Then
        dict.Add arr1(i, 1) & " " & Format(arr1(i, 2), "hh:mm"), arr1(i, 3) 'the key and its initial value
    Else
        'add to existing value the new one, for the same existing key:
        dict(arr1(i, 1) & " " & Format(arr1(i, 2), "hh:mm")) = _
              dict(arr1(i, 1) & " " & Format(arr1(i, 2), "hh:mm")) + arr1(i, 3)
    End If
 Next
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr2) 'iterate through the second array elements, create uniques keys and add values
    If Not dict.Exists(arr2(i, 1) & " " & Format(arr2(i, 2), "hh:mm")) Then
        dict.Add arr2(i, 1) & " " & Format(arr2(i, 2), "hh:mm"), arr2(i, 3) 'create a key if it not existing
    Else
        'add to existing value the new one, for the same existing key:
        dict(arr2(i, 1) & " " & Format(arr2(i, 2), "hh:mm")) = _
            dict(arr2(i, 1) & " " & Format(arr2(i, 2), "hh:mm")) + arr2(i, 3)
    End If
 Next
 'combining the arrays in the final one, using a not well known method:
 arrFin = Application.Transpose(Array(dict.Keys, dict.Items))

 'drop the created array contents at once:
 sh.Range("J2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Please, test the way I am suggesting and send some feedback.

Comment: @cs0679: Did you find some time to test the above solution/code? If tested, didn't it solve your problem?

Comment: @FanuDuru Thanks for that, it didn't quite do what I needed but gave me enough of a steer to use Dictionaries and Date/Hour keys which worked.  Thanks

Comment: @cs0679: But **what is different between the code I posted and what you needed**? I asked you how your looks but you did not answer anything. I imagined the above code just in order to visually show to you how the arrays are built and how they can be used in order to obtain what I understood you need. What else should I show in order to answer your question, which does not provide anything about the real arrays to be used?

Comment: @cs0679: I, of course, could show you only a way to proceed...

Comment: @FanuDuru my original question didn’t phrase it very well - i wanted to align the datasets on time/hour and keep the values from both arrays separate (rather then summing). Based on your suggestion I used a dictionary with your date/hour key approach and an array for the items.